# "MySQL server has gone away" error, I don't think it is a timeout

Tags: php, sql, database, timeout

I am trying to import an SQL dump via PHP. I have the following code.

```
    @mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("Cannot connect to DB!");
    @mysql_select_db("great_database") or die("Cannot select DB!");
    $query = file_get_contents('defaultDatabasePartOne.sql', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
    debug($query);
    $result = mysql_query($query);      
    debug($result);

    $error = mysql_error();
    debug($error);
```

I know it is correctly loading my file, because it debugs $query, which is the file. I removed comments from the file, but it still has line breaks, this wouldn't be a problem, would it?

I know that this error can have to do with a timeout, but I ran `SET GLOBAL wait_timeout =99999999999` and it didn't change anything so i think that might not be it? I am not experienced in SQL how can I fix this?

Here is the example for @chris:

```
CREATE TABLE `access_tokens` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `token` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `token` (`token`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Found [this](http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/php/27124-run-sql-file-through-php.html):**

Heres the function i used to do this operation:
Thought i'd post it just for those who need it in the future.

- $url is the path to the sql file
- $nowhost is dbhost
- $nowdatabase is db
- $nowuser is db user
- $nowpass is db pass

Code:

```
function parse_mysql_dump($url,$nowhost,$nowdatabase,$nowuser,$nowpass){
    $link = mysql_connect($nowhost, $nowuser, $nowpass);
        if (!$link) {
           die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
        }

        // make foo the current db
        $db_selected = mysql_select_db($nowdatabase, $link);
        if (!$db_selected) {
           die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
        }
   $file_content = file($url);
   foreach($file_content as $sql_line){
     if(trim($sql_line) != "" && strpos($sql_line, "--") === false){
     //echo $sql_line . '<br>';
       mysql_query($sql_line);
     }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Also note that mysql_ functions in PHP 5.3 have been deprecated and you should find an alternative method if possible. More info here: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/241077-whats-wrong-with-mysql-functions/.

Comment: ok except sometimes in the dump it does stuff that is on more than one line. i added an example to my question (to keep line breaks). and then does it run that properly, or would it just run the line `CREATE TABLE 'access_tokens' (` and MySQL would get confused?

Answer (score 2):

How big is that dump? You could be exceeding the [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) limit (the max size a query can be going client->server).

As well, remember that a .sql file produced by mysqldump contains MULTIPLE queries. The PHP mysql drivers do not allow more than a single query statement to be executed via a single query() call. You'll never be able to load a dump this way without parseing the dump file into individual queries.